# Can't login after chown command

Tags: permissions, login, root, lock-screen, chmod

I just installed elementary OS dual booted with windows 10. After the installation. I saw that the `/` root directory has every file and folder locked. I can't rename, delete or create anything there. `Home` directory is fine. I ran

`sudo chown -R $USER: /`

command from internet to get permissions and all folders were unlocked. But now after reboot I can't login. It just doesn't show the login screen. It shows a black screen with blinking `_`.

I want to ask the following -

- Are the root directory folders locked by default? If they are, do I need to unlock them for some reason in future for installing some software or any other reason? If I need them unlocked for some purposes, how should I do it correctly?
- I pressed `Ctrl+Alt+F1` on black screen and I can login as my username. But couldn't do much. Can I reverse the process to login again? If yes how?
- I can see my windows disks under `other locations`. All files can be read but are locked which is fine and I want them to be like that. But is there any possibility that those files can be deleted by me by running some commands?

I am kind of new to linux. I don't understand when I am the only user, why root has the permissions. And if root has the permissions, I am only one using the OS so how to do things which only root has the permission to do? I tried googling this thing but couldn't understand it properly.

Comment: You just destroyed your system, time to reinstall.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking to do so only. But can you please answer the 3 points I have mentioned so that I don't mess up again after the reinstall.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites.

Answer (score 2):

You have realized by now that you have destroyed your system and need to reinstall. To clear up a misconception and answer your three questions:

The permissions, including the fact that an unprivileged user has no write access to `/`, are by design. Your user has write access to their home directory, and almost nothing else.

For system administration, you assume the role of super user or root by either issuing `sudo <cmd>`, or logging on as root directly. Your ElementaryOS  has `sudo` as the preferred way. If you need root access for a lot of actions, you can use `sudo -i` to just have the root privileges or `sudo -s` when you also want to have the environment set up for the root user. Then, you can update, install or whatever else is necessary. After `exit`, you are back to the normal user.

This is the correct way of doing things.

Login to a virtual terminal with your user doesn't change things outlined above, the restrictions for the unprivileged user still apply.

If your windows files are locked, they can be changed by root only. It depends on the default mount option if this is true or not. Ubuntu 20.04 has them mounted now with write right for everyone now by default. If they are locked for you, only root can change them.

Answer (score 0):

Try and read just a little about the Linux filesystem, and some of your questions might be answered already.

https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/linux-filesystem-explained/

Rule of thumb: Do not mess with root unless you know what you're doing - it's really that simple.